Can I drive with a foreign driver license in other Schengen countries as a Schengen resident?
I'm living in Germany and I have a foreign driver license. With my license I could drive as a tourist in any European country. However, since I'm living in Germany for longer than 6 months my license is not valid in Germany. I can't exchange my driver licence to a German one and my path for driving in Germany would be to do driving school and the exams again.
According to this answer, it might be a problem to have a driver license from a place you are not a resident. However, my country of origin doesn't register residency like Schengen countries do, and I renewed my driver license a couple of times in my home country, even after I moved out of there.
To my understanding I can still use my license to drive in other Schengen countries as a tourist and I already did that. However, I wonder if other Schengen countries would consider me a resident or a tourist while I live in Germany? Does this vary depending on the country I'm visiting?

As far as I know there is no any kind of such an agreements between Shengen countries. You're only resident of Germany and only German law is applicable here. So you can't drive on a licence that is not recognisable in Germany for German residents (I suppose any EU license would work, not just German one, but not sure here). For all the other countries you're a tourist (again it might be different for EU citizens, but it's not a case as far as I understand the question) and can use any license recognisable in these countries.

Different countries have different definition of residence, sometimes multiple tests for different purposes but there is no way you would be considered a resident of other EU / Schengen country merely because you live in Germany. You are a resident of Germany, period. The thing is that it's not really where the problem lies or what the other Q&A is about. The real issue is that while being a resident of Germany, you are not supposed to get or renew a license anywhere else, certainly as far as German or EU law is concerned. That's really unambiguous.
